# How to have an object follow another objects rotation with a cap?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have two objects: the "track object," and the "follow object." The track object rotates according to the mouse (mouse-look). When the track object rotates, I would like the follow object rotate too (*follow* the track object; rotate till it matches the track object's rotation). I'm also looking to have this work with *time*, very similarly to the "track to" option in the "edit object" actuator: it does not immediately follow the track object by simply copying its rotation, but it takes x time to follow up (copy). By introducing time, the object takes time to follow up, which means that there is a possibility of the follow object's rotation to be way off (as the track object has moved a lot, and the follow object does not change instantly). To compensate, I am looking to have a cap. The follow object *must be* in a range. The range is the rotation. It will range from **(the track object's rotation  minus 10)** to **(the track object's rotation plus 10)**. This way, the follow object will *never* be far off the track object's rotation as it is kept in a range. A final note: I am looking to have this work in only the x and y axis. I would like an answer in python. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [transformation constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/transform/transformation.html) combined with a [limit location constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/transform/limit_location.html).

[image: Example animation]

In this example I am using the rotation of the z-axis to move the location of the x-axis. The mapping in the centre links the source z-axis to the destinations x-axis. The source and destination amounts provide a way to scale the transformation, when the source is at 0 degrees the destination will be at 0 and when the source is at 180 degrees the destination will be at 5, so 180 degrees rotation moves 5 units. If you change the destination location to 0 and 40 then the 180 degrees rotation will give 40 units of movement.

I then added a limit location so that the object will only move from -4 to 4 on the x-axis.

[image: Sample constraints panel]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you misunderstood the question, or I haven't explained it to the best of my abilities. Sorry for the inconvenience. I've completely rewritten the question to clarify. If there's anything unclear, you can ask me. Thanks.